# REST response over 8KB error when using SSL

Tags: java, rest, ssl

We have a REST service that is sending the content of a file. 
It is defined like below:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/files/{fileName}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
 Response getFileContent(@PathParam("fileName") @WebParam(name = "fileName") String fileName);
```

The application is running in a Tomcat having defined a connector like:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="c:\temp\ssl_key.ppk" keystorePass="changeme" maxThreads="200" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

The transfer of the files works just fine when requesting files under 8KB or when not using SSL.
The problem occurs only when the files are greater than 8KB and the stacktrace is the following:

```
    [http-nio-8443-exec-4] ERROR org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - Problem with writing the data, class java.io.File, ContentType: application/octet-stream
[http-nio-8443-exec-4] WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://test.com/}MyFileTest has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.handleWriteException(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:395)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.serializeMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.processResponse(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:252)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.copyAndCloseInput(IOUtils.java:166)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider.copyInputToOutput(BinaryDataProvider.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider.writeTo(BinaryDataProvider.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.writeMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1412)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.serializeMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:244)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.write(SecureNioChannel.java:521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
    ... 47 more
[http-nio-8443-exec-4] WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://test.com/}MyFileTest has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.wrapExceptionAsFault(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:252)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:151)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:804)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:735)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.write(SecureNioChannel.java:501)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
    ... 45 more
```

What is interesting is that for small files, an MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor is invoked in PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(Message) line: 308 while for the files bigger than 8KB it is used a JAXRSOutInterceptor that is using chunks.
Aparently, the first chunk with bytes from 0 to 8191 seems to be sent without any error while trying to send the second chunk from 8192 to 16383 throws the exception above.
Trying to call the REST from firefox gives the error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443. SSL received a record with an incorrect Message Authentication Code. Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_READ
```

The same error is given when executing from localhost but also from another machine.

An ajax request for the large files (large files meaning files of about 20 KB :-) ) give the same exception while for the smaller files is OK.

Nevertheless, when using the RESTClient from WizToold.org, the large files are also received OK.
As all investigations and tries failed so far, I wonder if anyone have any idea what could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Apache Tomcat/8.0.47. I tried everything but eventually I just used org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol instead of org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol and that fixed it for me.